# Errors that occur when converting dp to px in Android

Tags: android, textview

I'm using this code to change dp to px.

```java
public static int DpToPixel(Context context, int DP) {
    float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, DP, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    return (int) px;
}
```

### Problem

When creating TextView programmatically, set the width and height in pixels, as shown in the line below.

```
val width = DpToPixel(requireContext(), 96)
val height = DpToPixel(requireContext(), 14)

val textView = TextView(requireContext()).apply {
    layoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(width, height)
}
```

As a result, I thought that the width of textView would be 96dp and **the height would be 14dp**.

However, when I actually checked, **the height of the textView was set to 13dp**.

### Qusetion

1. How can i resolve error occured when converted dp to px?
2. Is there anyway creating `TextView` using width and height in DP unit?

Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: What a magical `TextView` you are using, in my android world I don't have constructor with width and height params. How do you measure height of `TextView`?

Comment: @Sky It's my mistake. I modified it, so please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update layout params after adding view to parent view group:

```
val txt = TextView(requireContext())
parentView.addView(txt)
txt.updateLayoutParams<ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams> { // Update width and height
    width = YOUR_DP_WIDTH
    height = YOUR_DP_HEIGHT
}
```

Check measured width and height via `viewTreeObserver`:

```
txt.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object: ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
    override fun onGlobalLayout() {
        txt.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
        Log.e("MEASURE", "W: ${txt.measuredWidth}, H: ${txt.measuredHeight}") // Here you can check measured width and height
        Log.e("MEASURE", "ConvertedW: ${YOUR_DP_WIDTH}, ConvertedH: ${YOUR_DP_HEIGHT}") // And compare sizes with converted values 
    }
})
```

Better to extract needed values from dimension resources:

```
val txtWidth = resources.getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.txt_width) // Int
val txtWidth = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.txt_width) // Rounded Int
val txtWidth = resources.getDimension(R.dimen.txt_width) // Float
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Rounded Int is good way for me.